# ERROR: Invalid argument while trying to accept a connection from a client

Tags: c, tcp

I'm trying to connect a client to a server using TCP. I suppose my client does correctly his job, but server can't accept the connection.
Here is my code:

SERVER:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int port, sock, newsock, thread_pool_size, queue_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    struct sockaddr *serverptr = ( struct sockaddr * )&server;
    struct sockaddr *clientptr = ( struct sockaddr * )&client;
    struct hostent *rem;
    socklen_t clientlen;
    pthread_t thr;
    int i, err, status;

    if(argc != 7)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./dataServer -p <port> -s <thread_pool_size> -q <queue_size>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "-p") == 0)
        {
            port = atoi(argv[++i]);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0)
        {
            thread_pool_size = atoi(argv[++i]);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-q") == 0)
        {
            queue_size = atoi(argv[++i]);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Wrong Input < %s >\n", argv[i]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d %d\n", port, thread_pool_size, queue_size);

    /* Create socket */
    if((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror_exit("socket");
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;       /* Internet domain */
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(port);      /* The given port */

    /* Bind socket to address */
    if(bind(sock, serverptr, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror_exit("bind");
    }

    /* Listen for connections */
    if(listen(sock, 5) < 0)
    {
        perror_exit("listen");
    }

    printf("Listening for connections to port %d\n", port);

    while(1)
    {
        /* accept connection */
        if((newsock = accept(sock, clientptr, &clientlen)) < 0)
        {
            //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            perror_exit("accept");
        }

        if((rem = gethostbyaddr((char *) &client.sin_addr.s_addr, sizeof(client.sin_addr.s_addr), client.sin_family)) == NULL)
        {
            herror("gethostbyaddr");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Accepted connection from %s\n", rem->h_name);

        close(sock);

        if((err = pthread_create(&thr, NULL, (void*)thread_f, (int *)newsock)))
        {
            perror_exit("pthread_create");
            exit(1); 
        }

        if((err = pthread_join(thr, (void **) &status)))
        {
            perror_exit("pthread_join");
            exit(1); 
        }

        close(newsock);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

CLIENT:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int port, sock, i;
    char buf[30];
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct sockaddr *serverptr = (struct sockaddr*)&server;
    struct hostent *rem;
    char server_ip[15];

    if(argc != 7)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./remoteClient -i <server_ip> -p <server_port> -d <directory>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "-i") == 0)
        {
            strcpy(server_ip, argv[++i]);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-p") == 0)
        {
            port = atoi(argv[++i]);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-d") == 0)
        {
            strcpy(buf, argv[++i]);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Wrong Input < %s >\n", argv[i]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    printf("%s %d %s\n", server_ip, port, buf);

    /* Create socket */
    if((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror_exit("socket");
    }

    /* Find server address */
    if((rem = gethostbyname(server_ip)) == NULL)
    {   
        herror("gethostbyname"); exit(1);
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(&server.sin_addr, rem->h_addr, rem->h_length);
    server.sin_port = htons(port);

    /* Initiate connection */
    if(connect(sock, serverptr, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror_exit("connect");
    }

    if (write(sock, buf, sizeof(buf)) < 0)
    {
        perror_exit("write");
    }

    close(sock);

    printf("ok\n");

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to run them:

./dataServer -p 12500 -s 2 -q 2

./remoteClient -i localhost -p 12500 -d ./dir/file_1

Don't mind for the rest of my code.
Can you help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated comment, but I must say, it is good to see code with some error handling :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `accept` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) (my emphasis)

> The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the **caller must
>   initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed
>   to by addr**; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer
>   address.

You pass in an uninitialised variable.  You need to initialise this to give the size of the buffer `clientptr` points to

```
socklen_t clientlen = sizeof(client);
```

After this, you should move the line

```
close(sock);
```

past the end of your `while` loop.  Your next error is caused by the second iteration of the loop operating on a handle you have closed.

Comment: I did the initialization of the clientlen and now I have another error: "Bad file descriptor". The weird here is that my program first prints "Accepted connection from localhost" and then shows me the error. How does it keep going and then stop?